# How to read multiple digit number from a string

Tags: c, string, integer, string-formatting

I am trying to pass a string S as input. Here the string S can contain multiple integer values followed by an alphabet. The program must expand the alphabets based on the previous integer value.

Consider the Input: `4a5h`
For which the Output: `aaaahhhhh`, that is 4 times `a` and 5 times `h`

Also for Input: `10a2b`
Output: `aaaaaaaaaabb`, that is 10 times `a` and 2 times `b`

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[1000], alp[1000];
    int num[1000];
    int n = 0;
    int i, j, k, m;
    k = 0;
    scanf("%[^\n]s", s);//Reads string until newline character is encountered
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        if (isalpha(s[i])) {
            alp[n] = s[i]; // alp[] stores the alphabets
            n += 1;
        } else {
            num[k] = s[i] - '0';// num[] stores the numbers
            k += 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (m = 0; m < num[i]; m++)
            printf("%c", alp[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But with this code I am not able to read 2 or 3 or a N digit number. So if the Input is `100q1z` then the `alp[]` array is fine but `num[]` array is not containing `100` and `1` as its elements instead `1` and `0` are its elements.

How do I correct this code?

Comment: 1) `k` should be `0` as the initial value.

Comment: Thanks for that @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the loop to handle as many digits are present successively int the string:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char s[1000], alp[1000];
    int num[1000];
    int i, k = 0, m, n;

    //Read string until newline character is encountered
    if (scanf("%999[^\n]", s) == 1) {
        for (i = 0; s[i]; i++) {
            n = 1;
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)s[i])) {
                for (n = s[i++] - '0'; isdigit((unsigned char)s[i]); i++) {
                     n = n * 10 + s[i] - '0';
                }
            }
            if (isalpha((unsigned char)s[i])) {
                alp[k] = s[i];  // store the letter
                num[k] = n;   // store the number
                k += 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            for (m = 0; m < num[i]; m++)
                putchar(alp[i]);
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- include `<ctype.h>` to use `isalpha()`.
- protect the destination array of `scanf` by passing a maximum number of characters and check the return value.
- the format for converting a non empty line is simply `%[^\n]`, the trailing `s` is incorrect. Note that unlike `fgets()`, this `scanf()` format will fail if the line is empty.
- you should always test the return value of `scanf()`.
- cast the `char` argument to `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior if `char` is signed and has a negative value.
- use `putchar(c)` to output a single character instead of `printf("%c", c);`

Comment: That is perfectly fine.I guess there is a typo at the inner if loop.Thanks for the help @chqrlie

Answer (score 1):

The part of else-bolock must be looped.

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> //need this for isalpha and isdigit

int main(void){
    char s[1000], alp[1000];
    int num[1000];
    int m = 0, n = 0;
    int i, j;
    unsigned char ch;//convert char to unsigned char before use isalpha and isdigit

    scanf("%999[^\n]", s);//remove s after [^\n] and Add limit
    for(i = 0; ch = s[i]; i++){//replace strlen each loop
        if(isalpha(ch)){
            alp[n++] = s[i];
        } else if(isdigit(ch)){
            num[m] = 0;
            while(isdigit(ch = s[i])){
                num[m] = num[m] * 10 + s[i] - '0';
                ++i;
            }
            ++m;
            --i;//for ++i of for-loop
        } else {//Insufficient as validation
            printf("include invalid character (%c).\n", ch);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < num[i]; j++)
            printf("%c", alp[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will parse `a5d4` and produce `aaaaadddd` and invoke undefined behavior on `a`, and `5ab`, etc.

Comment: @chqrlie yes, Insufficient as validation.

Comment: Well on the other hand, the specification is insufficient too ;-)

Comment: That was quick @BLUEPIXY.I was trying to figure out different methods to get a multidigit number but all were in vain

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified it clearly.The input can be only of alternating number and character.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that when you encounter a digit in the string, you are considering it as a number and storing it in num array. 
This is fine if you have only **single digit numbers** in the array. 
For multidigit numbers do this- 
**read the string for digits until you find a alphabet, form a number using the obtained digits and then save it to num array**.
I m leaving the code for you.